# Probability that $\frac{x}{y}$ is close to an even number, $0 <x,y<1$

Tags: probability

> Two real numbers $x,y$ are choosen uniformely from $(0,1)$. What is
>   the probability that the closest integer to $\frac{x}{y}$ is even? Can
>   it be expressed in the form $r+s\pi$ for $r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$.

So, the number $\frac{x}{y}$ could potentially be very small or very large. If $\frac{x}{y}$ is close to an even number, then $2k-0.5<\frac{x}{y}<2k+0.5$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. I used online plot to get an idea of what $\frac{x}{y}$ look like.

[image]

Comment: Here's how I might start the problem. $x/y$ is the slope of a line through the origin. Think about how the lines with odd and even integral slope divide up the part of the unit circle in the first quadrant. The hint that the solution might involve $\pi$ suggests that this start might lead to a solution.

Comment: Hint: you might start by computing the CDF of $x/y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The lines of constant $x/y$ are just straight lines through the origin. So if $k>=1$, the region $B$ given by $2k-\frac12<x/y<2k+\frac12$ is a triangle, with height $1$ (along the $x-$axis) and base $\dfrac{1}{2k-\frac12}-\dfrac{1}{2k+\frac12}$ (along the $y$-axis), with area $\frac12\left(\dfrac{1}{2k-\frac12}-\dfrac{1}{2k+\frac12}\right)=\dfrac{1}{4k-1}-\dfrac{1}{4k+1}$.

And the region $A$ given by $x/y<\frac12$ is a triangle of area $\frac14$. So the total probability is
$$\frac14+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{4k-1}-\dfrac{1}{4k+1}\right)$$

And [Leibniz's formula for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) says that
$$1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\cdots=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
So
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{4k-1}-\dfrac{1}{4k+1}\right)=\frac13-\frac15+\frac17-\frac19+\cdots$$

is equal to $1-\pi/4$, and we get a total probability of
$$\frac14 + 1 -\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{5-\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

At $k\in \mathbb{N}$: $0<y<1$, $0<x<1$, $(2k-\frac12)y < x < (2k+\frac12)y$ $\Rightarrow$ $\left(0 < y \leq \frac{1}{2k+\frac12} \land (2k-\frac12)y < x < (2k+\frac12)y\right) \lor$ $\left(\frac{1}{2k+\frac12} < y < \frac{1}{2k-\frac12} \land (2k-\frac12)y < x < 1\right)$

$$P_k=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2k+\frac12}} \int_{(2k-\frac12)y}^{(2k+\frac12)y} dx dy+\int_{\frac{1}{2k+\frac12}}^{\frac{1}{2k-\frac12}} \int_{(2k-\frac12)y }^1 dx dy=\frac{2}{(4k-1)(4k+1)}$$

At $k=0$:  $0<y<1$, $0<x<1$, $(2k-\frac12)y < x < (2k+\frac12)y$ $\Rightarrow$ $\left(0 < y < 1 \land 0 < x < \frac12 y\right)$

$$P_0=\int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac12 y} dx dy=\frac14$$

$$P=\frac14+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}{(4k-1)(4k+1)}=\frac{1}{4}+1-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{5-\pi}{4}$$